# why ain't i getting the exact size on preview of vs code live server

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I write some CSS and watch it on a live server it looks exactly what I want even the developer tool on chrome shows the exact size but it changes when I open it separately from
my root directory. Please try to solve it.

```css
body{
  background: #ebf8fe;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed #b5b5b5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p{
  font-family: Rubik;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

p, span{
  color: #b5b5b5;
}
div:hover p{ 
  color: #2196f3;
}
div:hover span{ 
  color: #2196f3;
}

span{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div:hover{
  border: 2px solid #2196f3;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&plus;</span><p>New Project</p></div>
```

Comment: Hi There Could You Add Your Entire HTML Header Code. It Would Be Easier For Us To Explain Then

Comment: Ok i'll do it and do you even want css